# How to install jenkins plugins in offline mode

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am sitting behind proxy. I can not bypass it as I am not allowed to download anything on this linux box. I don't have root privilege either.

I have deployed jenkins.war on apache tomcat. Also, downloaded all necessary Jenkins plugins and placed it as shown below:

```
jenkins
+apache-tomcat-8.5.12/webapps/jenkins
+apache-tomcat-8.5.12/webapps/jenkins.war
+plugins
```

Can anyone please let me know is there any way I can simply point to `'jenkins/plugins'` directory path in some config file to install plugins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue. Copied all plugins @ `/home/appuser/.jenkins/plugins`. When we deploy jenkins.war on apache tomcat it creates jenkins-home @ `/home/user/.jenkins`

Comment: exactly is the same dir like JENKINS_HOME/plugins
with tomcat is the .jenkins dir. please make the question resolved

Answer (score 1):

**On the master**

Assuming a .hpi file has been explicitly downloaded, the administrator can manually place the .hpi file in a specific location on the file system.

Copy the downloaded .hpi` file into the JENKINS_HOME/plugins directory on the Jenkins master (for example, on Debian systems JENKINS_HOME is generally /var/lib/jenkins).

The master will need to be restarted before the plugin is loaded and made available in the Jenkins environment.

pay attention for the dependencies plugins some plugins claim other plugins

[Jenkins plugins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/)

Comment: I have deployed Jenkins war on Apache tomcat. So please let me know where should I put these plugins.